# How can get access the object 'view' in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I add data the db.sqlite by sql script.
For get access to the table:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'db.sqlite'))
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine)
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()
session.query(Base.classes[tablename])
```

db.sqlite has object view "view_xxx" which created by sql script. How can I get acсess to the view?

Comment: I updated my answer to include both the Core and ORM way to reflect a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + 'db.sqlite')
session = Session(engine)
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine)

QUERY_TO_DB = 'SELECT * FROM property_1, property_2'

class CreateView(Executable, ClauseElement):
    def __init__(self, name, select):
        self.name = name
        self.select = select

@compiles(CreateView)
def visit_create_view(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "CREATE VIEW %s AS %s" % (
        element.name,
        element.select)

try:
    with engine.connect() as conn, conn:
        createview = CreateView('name_view', QUERY_TO_DB)
        conn.execute(createview)
except Exception as e:
    print('Failed to create view: ', e)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reflect a view in the same way as reflecting a table.

Say we have a manager table view created from an employee table. To reflect and
access the data on this view with SQLAlchemy Core, we can:

```py
metadata = MetaData()
engine = create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL,
)

manager_view = Table("manager", metadata, autoload_with=engine)

# list view columns: "id", "name", etc.
print("manager_view columns:", [c.name for c in manager_view.columns])

with engine.connect() as conn:
    stmt = (
        select(manager_view)
        .order_by(manager_view.c.id) # "id" is a column listed above
    )
    for row in conn.execute(stmt):
        print(row.id, row.name) # "id", "name"
```

This only reflects the single view.

Or, to do it the ORM way:

```py
engine = create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL,
)
Base: AutomapBase = automap_base()

# You have to add the view to `Base.metadata` first with a table,
# so reflection will work on it.
# You can also directly use the Table with Core like above.
Table(
    "manager",
    Base.metadata,  # this is how the view is recognized
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),  # PK is necessary
    autoload_with=engine,
)

# Reflect all tables and get the Manager model:
Base.prepare(autoload_with=engine)
print("Classes reflected:", Base.classes.keys())
Manager = Base.classes.manager

# Use it as you normally would:
with Session(engine) as session:
    for manager in session.scalars(select(Manager)):
        print(manager.id, manager.name, manager.hire_date)
```